# Flow :: There is a checkbox called "option" in opportunity, if the checkbox is checked the email should be send to public group users

Tags: lightning, visual-workflow

[image][image][image][image][image][image]While debuging[image]
Error Occurred:

0 recipients

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're trying to send the email to a Group, not the members of that Group. The Email field on Group is only available for Case queues as per the [Group Object Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_group.htm) documentation.

To send the email to each participant, you actually need to retrieve GroupMember records that are related to the particular group. In this case you'll need to first retrieve the Group Id using you're existing Get Records, then use that ID to gather the Group Member records.

From here, you'll need to use a Loop to create a collection of the User IDs from the Group Member records, using the UserOrGroupId field.

Next you'll be able to retrieve the User records, using an 'IN' operator on the ID field and the collection of IDs that you created from the Group Member records.

Finally, you can loop through the User's add use them as the recipient. To help preserve the limits and reduce the number of email actions you're using, I'd actually suggest that you create a comma separated list of the User's email addresses in the loop, and use a single Send Email action rather than doing the actually sending in a loop.